# import extra project which is one level above of main gradle project file

Tags: java, gradle

I have a big project which depends on an another project. My git structure is following:

```
/gitRepository
|
|--> /ConfigFacade
|    |
|    |--> /ejbModule/
|    |    --> META-INF/
|    |    --> com/myApp/com/name/myClass.java
|--> /myMainApp
|    |
|    |--> /src/
|    |    --> main/java/com/name/allJavaFiles.java
|    |--> build.gradle
```

How should I add correctly ConfigFacade project to my gradle file?

I tried something like that but it doesnt work

```
dependencies {
    providedCompile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0' 
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet.jsp', name: 'javax.servlet.jsp-api', version: '2.3.1'
    providedCompile project(':ConfigFacade')
}
```

How gradle should import another project one level above where gradle file is?

Comment: what IDE are you using Eclipse or Intellij?

Comment: Im using Eclipse but I need to create a war file using gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `settings.gradle` file next to your `build.gradle` file with the following content:

```
includeFlat 'ConfigFacade'
```

That should do the trick. See also the [docs of `includeFlat`](https://docs.gradle.org/6.2.2/javadoc/org/gradle/api/initialization/Settings.html#includeFlat-java.lang.String...-).